# "widely consumed" or "widely consuming" when describing bananas

Tags: adjectives

I was wondering which word is correct in the below sentence:

> 1. Banana is one of the most widely **consumed** fruits.
> 2. Banana is one of the most widely **consuming** fruits.

I would be grateful if elaborate on the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only example 1, "consumed", is correct: the banana is eaten.

For example 2, "consuming" would have to mean that the banana was doing the eating. They might consume resources while being grown, but no one would say that.

Comment: could you please give me the same explanation about "The hotel parking lot" regarding why we do not say "The hotel parked lot"

Comment: could it be a convincing explanation if we say because "the parking lot" belongs to "Hotel"?

Comment: That question is completely new, so you should post it separately.